# Algorithm to optimize chord progressions identification in a song?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I develop a music application and I need to find an "optimal" combination of standard chord/harmonic progressions used in a song. The standard progressions in my database are 2 or 4 chords, and are not "exclusive".

For example if a part of a song uses the chord sequence `Fm7-Bb7-Eb7M-Ab7M`, it will match the standard progressions `Fm7-Bb7` (II-V), `Bb7-Eb7M` (V-I), but also `Fm7-Bb7-Eb7M-Ab7M` (II-V-I-IV).  Of course a song can have any number of chords, and very often there are
chord sequences which do not correspond to any standard chord progression.

The optimal combination of standard progressions I'm looking for is the one which minimizes the number of song measures not covered by any standard progression.

I struggle to find the right way to tackle this, any help is welcome.

EDIT:

Indeed @user58697, it's much easier to explain with a sequence of letters and a vocabulary of 2 or 4-letter words, e.g:

- text=`ABCDDCEFGHX`
- vocabulary=`ABCD, CDDC, EFGH, AB`

I want to pick the words so that I minimize the number of letters which are not part of a word:

- text=`{ABCD}DC{EFGH}X` : 3 letters not part of a word
- text=`{AB}{CDDC}{EFGH}X` : best solution

With a long text there are usually several best solutions.

Comment: Your post is completely unintelligible for someone ignorant of this guitar (?) notation and vocabulary (like I am).

Comment: Could you please describe the term "chord progression identification" and what "optimized" in that context is?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am equally ignorant in music, but the problem is pretty clear. We have a text and a vocabulary. The goal is to partition the text into segments to minimize the segments not in the vocabulary. The only clarification needed is a definition of _minimize_.

Comment: If your standard progressions was `{ ABC, BC, A }` and your song is `ABC`, the answer would be 1, `{ ABC }` is not matched in the optimum, `{ BC, A }` are (non-overlapping?) Sounds like dynamic programming would help.

Comment: @user58697: please explain the annotations with Roman numbers.

Comment: @YvesDaoust https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numeral_analysis

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: so how do these interact with the standard progressions ? (Note that the question was to user58697.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust The Roman numerals are defined with respect to a key (so Fm7-Bb7 is II7-V7 in the key of Eb), but if we just have the song chords, we don't know (and possibly can't know) what that key is. OP should clarify the conditions under which overlaps (pivots IIRC) are OK, in particular, do the keys have to match or not?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: this is why I disagree with "the problem is pretty clear".

Comment: I edited the question, it should be much more clear now.